# C# Multithreading for three threads working in parallel and sending data to each other and working in order

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a C# windows form program that uses three threads.
*The first thread is responsible for reading files from input folder and reading all text from each file then send data as string to the second thread using a Queue.
*The second thread is responsible on parsing the string got from the first thread, if the string was a number then send this number to the third thread also using a Queue.
*The third thread is responsible on creating file for the number got from thread 2.
Also I should have a Timer that runs thread 1 every 4 seconds for example until pressing stop.( should thread 2 and thread 3 when thread 1 runs after 4 seconds ?)
 Note That the three threads should be running in parallel and should be in the correct order Thread 1 then Thread 2 then Thread 3 and should be getting and sending data for each other.
Below is an image for what i described below and some of the code that I used in my program. 
Please I want your help I'm stuck in this ....
[image]

Code is :

> form1.cs Class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Threading;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace Mltithreading
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public ConcurrentQueue<string> _queue = new ConcurrentQueue<string>();
    public Queue<string> Queue1result = new Queue<string>();
    public Queue<string> TestQueue = new Queue<string>();
    public Queue<string> Queue2result = new Queue<string>();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
  /*  private Timer timer1; 
    public void InitTimer()
    {
        timer1 = new Timer();
        timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
        timer1.Interval = 2000; // in miliseconds
        timer1.Start();
    } */
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        isonline();
    }
    public void isonline()
    {

            //
            // The user selected a folder and pressed the OK button.
            // We print the number of files found.
            //
            string[] files =                   Directory.GetFiles(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath);
            MessageBox.Show(files[0]);
            var a = files[1];
            var dir = new DirectoryInfo(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath);
            FileInfo[] f = dir.GetFiles();
            foreach (System.IO.FileInfo fi in f)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}: {2}", fi.Name, fi.LastAccessTime, fi.Length);
            }
            MessageBox.Show("Files found: " + files.Length.ToString(), "Message");

    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        DialogResult result = folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog();
        if (result == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            //
            // The user selected a folder and pressed the OK button.
            // We print the number of files found.
            //
            textBox1.Text = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;
    /*    try
        {
            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath);     
            var dir = new DirectoryInfo(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath);
            var output = folderBrowserDialog2.SelectedPath;

            FileInfo[] f = dir.GetFiles();
            Queue<FileInfo> Q = new Queue<FileInfo>(f);

            while (Q.Count > 0)
            {
                FileInfo current = Q.Dequeue();
                Console.WriteLine(current);
                // Process 'current'
            }
            foreach (System.IO.FileInfo fi in f)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}: {2}", fi.Name, fi.LastAccessTime, fi.Length);
            }
            MessageBox.Show("Files found: " + files.Length.ToString(), "Message");
        }
        catch (Exception excep)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("An error occurred: '{0}'", excep);
        } */
        }
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult result = folderBrowserDialog2.ShowDialog();
        if (result == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            //
            // The user selected a folder and pressed the OK button.
            // We print the number of files found.
            //
            textBox2.Text = folderBrowserDialog2.SelectedPath;

        }
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string input = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;
        string output = folderBrowserDialog2.SelectedPath;
        var result = Thread1Start(input, output);
        Console.WriteLine("Is thread Still Running :{0}", result);
        //var firstThread = new Thread1();
        var secondThread = new Thread2();
        var thirdThread = new Thread3();
        //Thread thread = new Thread(() => th.Readfiles(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath, folderBrowserDialog2.SelectedPath));
        //Thread thread1 = new Thread(delegate() { Queue1result = firstThread.Readfiles(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath, folderBrowserDialog2.SelectedPath); });
        //Thread thread3 = new Thread(() =>second.test(valueQueue));
        Thread thread2 = new Thread(delegate() { Queue2result = secondThread.test(TestQueue); });
        Thread thread3 = new Thread(() => thirdThread.CreateFiles(Queue2result,output));
        //Thread thread5 = new Thread(second.run);
        //thread1.Start();
       // thread1.Join();
        thread2.Start();
        //thread2.Join();
        thread3.Start();
        //thread1.Start();
        //thread1.Join();
        //thread2.Start();
        //thread1.Join(TimeSpan.Zero);
        //Console.WriteLine(thread1.Join(TimeSpan.Zero));
       // new System.Threading.Timer (ThreadTimer, "Thread 1 Started working...", 5000, 1000);


    }

    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
   /* public void ThreadTimer (object data)
    {
        string input = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;
        string output = folderBrowserDialog2.SelectedPath;
        var result = Thread1Start(input, output);
       Console.WriteLine("Is thread Still Running :{0}",result);         
    }
    */
    public bool Thread1Start(string input, string output)
    {
        var firstThread = new Thread1();
        Thread thread1 = new Thread(delegate() { Queue1result = firstThread.Readfiles(input, output); });
        TestQueue = Queue1result;
        thread1.Start();
        Console.WriteLine("thread 1 start");
        var state = thread1.Join(TimeSpan.Zero);
        var secondThread = new Thread2();
        var thirdThread = new Thread3();
        //Thread thread = new Thread(() => th.Readfiles(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath, folderBrowserDialog2.SelectedPath));
        //Thread thread1 = new Thread(delegate() { Queue1result = firstThread.Readfiles(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath, folderBrowserDialog2.SelectedPath); });
        //Thread thread3 = new Thread(() =>second.test(valueQueue));
        Thread thread2 = new Thread(delegate() { Queue2result = secondThread.test(Queue1result); });
        Thread thread3 = new Thread(() => thirdThread.CreateFiles(Queue2result, output));
        //Thread thread5 = new Thread(second.run);
        //thread1.Start();
        // thread1.Join();
        thread2.Start();
        //thread2.Join();
        thread3.Start();
        return state;
    }
}
}
```

> Thread1.cs class

```
 here using System;
 using System.IO;
 using  System.Text;
 using  System.Threading;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Threading.Tasks;
 using System.Windows.Forms;
 namespace Mltithreading
{
class Thread1
{
    public void run()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            int iterations = 10;
            try
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("From Thread 1");
                    Thread.Sleep(2000);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }
        }
    }
    public  Queue<string> Readfiles(string inputDirectoryPath, string outputDirectoryPath)
    {   Queue<string> thread1Queue = new Queue<string>();
        try
        {
            var dir = new DirectoryInfo(inputDirectoryPath);
            FileInfo[] f = dir.GetFiles();

            foreach (System.IO.FileInfo fi in f)
            {
                var filePath = fi.DirectoryName + "\\" + fi.Name;
                //File.Copy(filePath, outputDirectoryPath + "\\" + fi.Name);
                // Open the file to read from.
                string readText = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
                thread1Queue.Enqueue(readText);
                Console.WriteLine(readText);
                Console.WriteLine("thread 1 call read files method ");
                //Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}: {2}", fi.Name, fi.LastAccessTime, fi.Length);
            }


        }
        catch (Exception excep)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("An error occurred: '{0}'", excep);
        }
        return thread1Queue;
    }


}
}
```

> Thread2.cs class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

 namespace Mltithreading
{
class Thread2
{
    public void run()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            int iterations = 10;
            try
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("From Thread 2");
                    Thread.Sleep(2000);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }
        }
    }

    public Queue<string> test(Queue<string> list)
    {
        Queue<string> thread2Queue = new Queue<string>();
        while (list.Count > 0)
        {
            try
            {
                var a = list.Dequeue();
                Console.WriteLine(a);
                int j;
                if (Int32.TryParse(a, out j))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("parsed the string {0} to integer and sent to thread 3", j);
                    thread2Queue.Enqueue(a);
                }
                else
                    Console.WriteLine("String could not be parsed to integer.");
                Console.WriteLine("thread 2 parsing string from thread 1");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }


        }
        return thread2Queue;
    }

}
```

}

> Thread3.cs Class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

 namespace Mltithreading
{
class Thread3
{
    public void run()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            int iterations = 10;
            try
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("From Thread 3");
                    Thread.Sleep(2000);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }
        }
    }
    public void CreateFiles(Queue<string> list, string outputDirectoryPath)
    {
        while (list.Count > 0)
        {
            string format = "MM-dd-yyyy--HH-mm-ss";
            DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
            string filename = date.ToString(format);
            string file = outputDirectoryPath + "\\" + filename + ".txt";
            var a = list.Dequeue();
            FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(file);
            if (!fi.Exists)
            {
                fi.Create().Dispose();
                System.IO.File.WriteAllText(file,a);
                Console.WriteLine("creating new text file {{0}}",file);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("file already exists");
            }
            Console.WriteLine(a);
            Console.WriteLine("Thread 3 creating File with date name");
            Console.WriteLine(date.ToString(format));

        }

    }
}
}
```

Thank you very much for your help .

Comment: Be sure to have look at building data pipelines with `BlockingCollection<T>` like outlined in this msdn article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff963548.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I won´t comment on all, there´s too much stuff to talk about, but let´s have a look at your first thread.

```
Thread thread1 = new Thread(delegate() { Queue1result = firstThread.Readfiles(input, output); });
```

This line will create a thread that will replace the existing instance in your field Queue1Result (have a look at naming conventions, please!) once after reading some files (if existing). If executed again, The existing queue goes out of scope and will be replaced with a new one, probably not what you want to do.

You need to create those queue instances just once (type to use is ConcurrentQueue), those should then be used as a parameter running the thread procedure. So, redeclare the queues to readonly ConcurrentQueue to create the instances for your fields(give them a good "speaking" name, btw).

```
public readonly ConcurrentQueue<string> _textFromFilesQueue = new ConcurrentQueue<string>();
```

Once started, you want to regularly look after files again, so your code has to contain a loop.
This loop to be executed should be terminable from outside / other threads using a CancellationToken. Lets add a CancellationTokenSource to Form 1:

```
public CancellationTokenSource CancellationTokenSource { get; set; }
```

Your execution code for the first thread could / should look like this:

```
    public void Readfiles(string inputDirectoryPath, string outputDirectoryPath, ConcurrentQueue<string> queue, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            try
            {
                var dir = new DirectoryInfo(inputDirectoryPath);
                FileInfo[] f = dir.GetFiles();

                foreach (System.IO.FileInfo fi in f)
                {
                    var filePath = Path.Combine(fi.DirectoryName, fi.Name);
                    //File.Copy(filePath, outputDirectoryPath + "\\" + fi.Name);
                    // Open the file to read from.
                    string textFromFile = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
                    queue.Enqueue(textFromFile);
                    Console.WriteLine(textFromFile);
                    Console.WriteLine("thread 1 call read files method ");
                    //Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}: {2}", fi.Name, fi.LastAccessTime, fi.Length);
                }
                Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
            }
            catch (Exception excep)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("An error occurred: '{0}'", excep);
                Throw excep;
            }
        }

    }
```

Do not build up a path by concatenating strings, use Path.Combine instead. Also, exceptions that happened should just be rethrown to ensure correct handling from other threads / tasks.

I would recommend using the TPL mechanisms instead of threads, it grants the system more flexibility in handling the tasks to be executed in a parallel manner. Have a look here : https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/dd460717(v=vs.110).aspx

So, creating and executing this task:

```
        CancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        Task task = new Task(() => Readfiles(input, output, _textFromFilesQueue, CancellationTokenSource.Token));
        task.Start();
```

Stopping the task:

```
        CancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
```

Be sure not to overwrite the TokenSource without calling Cancel(), else you are losing the ability to stop the tasks that have already started...

EDIT: If you really need to ignore TPL, here is the example to execute the reading method with a thread:

```
        Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() => Readfiles(input, output, _textFromFilesQueue, CancellationTokenSource.Token)));
        thread.Resume();
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help in this, but the read files method return type is a queue of strings , not parameter in order to let thread 2 get this queue to dequeue its elements and I want to ask you about how can I make the threads order and a timer to run the first thread ... and pls i want to know  if when thread 1 is repeated on a specific timer thread 2 and thread 3 should work in parallel without being stopped !! is that true or false ???

Comment: Well, i changed it to use void because it would be a design error to replace the queue. The queue itself is not something you want to create with your thread, you just want to put your results into it. Of course, other threads can use the same queue for either read or write operations. The ReadFiles method got a sleep command causing sleeping 5 seconds before looking for files again, you do not need to create a thread every 5 seconds. I do not really understand your questions about threads working "parallel without being stopped". That´s the point in using threads, isn´t it?

Answer (score 1):

Use very simple and clear code:

```
var inputTexts = new BlockingCollection<string>();
var inputNumbers = new BlockingCollection<string>();

var readFiles = Task.Run(() =>
{
    try
    {
        foreach (var file in Directory.EnumerateFiles("path", "searchPattern"))
        {
            string text = File.ReadAllText(file);
            inputTexts.Add(text);
        }
    }
    finally { inputTexts.CompleteAdding(); }
});

var processNumbers = Task.Run(() =>
{
    try
    {
        foreach (var text in inputTexts.GetConsumingEnumerable())
        {
            int result;
            if (int.TryParse(text, out result))
                inputNumbers.Add(text);
        }
    }
    finally { inputNumbers.CompleteAdding(); }
});

var createFiles = Task.Run(() =>
{
    foreach (var number in inputNumbers.GetConsumingEnumerable())
    {
        string path = ""; // set fileName
        File.WriteAllText(path, number);
    }
});

Task.WaitAll(readFiles, processNumbers, createFiles);
```

It guarantees the execution in the correct order.

You can easily add cancellation using `CancellationTokenSource`.

---

Ok. Here is a working application that uses threads and timer.

It is assumed that execution all threads is faster than the timer interval.

New threads starts with each timer tick. The old threads will continue to work if they have not yet ended.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Button stopButton;
        System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer;

        public Form1()
        {
            //InitializeComponent();

            stopButton = new Button { Parent = this, Text = "Stop" };
            stopButton.Click += StopButton_Click;

            timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
            timer.Interval = 1000;
            timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
            timer.Start();

            Text = "Start";
        }

        private void StopButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer.Stop();
            Text = "Stop";
        }

        private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var inputTexts = new BlockingCollection<string>();
            var inputNumbers = new BlockingCollection<string>();

            var readFiles = new Thread(() =>
            {
                try
                {
                    foreach (var file in Directory.EnumerateFiles("./Folder", "*.txt"))
                    {
                        string text = File.ReadAllText(file);
                        inputTexts.Add(text);
                    }
                }
                finally { inputTexts.CompleteAdding(); }
            });

            var processNumbers = new Thread(() =>
            {
                try
                {
                    foreach (var text in inputTexts.GetConsumingEnumerable())
                    {
                        int result;
                        if (int.TryParse(text, out result))
                            inputNumbers.Add(text);
                    }
                }
                finally { inputNumbers.CompleteAdding(); }
            });

            var createFiles = new Thread(() =>
            {
                int counter = 0;
                foreach (var number in inputNumbers.GetConsumingEnumerable())
                {
                    File.WriteAllText("./Folder2/" + counter + ".txt", number);
                    counter++;
                }
            });

            readFiles.Start();
            processNumbers.Start();
            createFiles.Start();

            readFiles.Join();
            processNumbers.Join();
            createFiles.Join();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but how we can make it as threads not tasks and how we can make a timer to run the first thread every number of seconds ?? can you help me in this please

Comment: A.H., why do you want to use Threads instead of Tasks? Tasks are just an abstraction, internally a task execution will be run utilizing a thread.

Comment: I have a task to do using threads, I'm just learning threads in the time being and need to do this using threads. very grateful if you can help me in it !

Comment: Yes I'm very thankful for this, I'm trying to work on it but i'm still not knowing how to run them in order and how to make a timer function for the first thread i'm seeing it complicated  don't know why !! sorry for my silly questions and appreciate your help :)

Comment: Thank you very much very gratefull @AlexanderPetrov

Comment: If I add Thread.sleep(1000) in one of the thread methods The form freezes, If I remove Thread.join it will not freeze do you why is that happening ? I want to use both Thread.join and Thread.sleep how can I do that !!

Comment: @A.H - The `Tick` event of `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` occurs on the GUI thread. Or use another timer (e.g. `System.Threading.Timer`), or don't use `Thread.Sleep` (for the use of this method in a decent society beat in the face). And most importantly, ask another question. Don't ask in the comments.

Comment: ok, Thank you for that. I did it using System.Threading.Timer in the button click like this  in the button cick i have( new System.Threading.Timer @(ThreadTimer, "Thread 1 working within time interval...",timer*1000, 1000);and the function ThreadTimer has @(        var firstThread = new Thread1();
            Thread thread1 = new Thread(() => firstThread.Read(input));
            thread1.IsBackground = true;
            thread1.Start();
            thread1.Join();
            //Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
        }). But still having the same issue